# Symfony2: Doctrine extension Softdeleteable is permanently deleting Translatable elements

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, soft-delete

I'm using the latest version `dev-master` of Doctrine extensions with Symfony2.7.0.
I added both extensions `Softdeleteable` and `Translatable` to my entity. The problem is that when the entity gets soft-deleted its translation gets hard-deleted.

Is there a workaround this?

**Edit**
I have found this [issue](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/754) on Github, but I can't make much of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the github issues and the proposed "fixes" and consulting experts I have decided that this was more trouble than its worth. 
The problem is obviously the listner, and I shouldn't be messing with the bundles under `vendor`.
When translatables get the 'delete' from my soft-deleted object, these "children" of my object are not really objects of their own thus can't be configured to be soft-deleted.

My solution is to add a `deletedAt` attribute, NULL by default and when in my controller I used to execute `$entityManager->delete($object)` I now, just have to change the value of `deletedAt` to the current DateTime. `$object->setDeletedAt($date)`.

And when retrieving objects I just add a clause `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE deletedAt IS NULL;`

This implies changing a lot of queries but it is the simplest option while waiting for a fix.